# Decomposition of Grassmannian

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, grassmannian

Let $V$ and $W$ be two vector spaces of dimension $n$ each. Then is there a decomposition of the Grassmannian $G(r, V\oplus W)$ in terms of $G(r,V)$ and $G(r,W)$ ? I am expecting something similar to the wedge decomposition. My guess is that it is the direct sum of cartesian products of $G(k,V)$ and $G(l,W)$ such that $k+l=r$. Is this true ?

Comment: For an answer see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/822470/exterior-power-commutes-with-direct-sum).

Comment: @DietrichBurde That answer is about the entire exterior algebra, while the OP would be interested only in the projectivization of the space of decomposable wedges in a given degree, no?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a similar result for Grassmannian.

Comment: In some sense one shouldn't expect such a decomposition. If there were one, it would induce a corresponding decomposition of the tangent space at any point $E \in G(r, V \oplus W)$, but we may identify canonically $T_E G(r, V \oplus W)$ with $E^* \otimes ((V \oplus W) / E)$. At a generic point, $E$ is transverse to both $V$ and $W$, and for such $E$ there is no way to rewrite $(V \oplus W) / E$ in a 'decomposed' way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is a reasonable way to construct $Gr(r,V\oplus W)$ from  the $Gr(k,V)$'s and $Gr(l, W)$'s.
For example $Gr(1,\mathbb C\oplus \mathbb C)=\mathbb P^1(\mathbb C)$, a complex projective variety of dimension $1$.
But the $Gr(k,\mathbb C)$'s are sets with just $1$ element if $k=0$ or $k=1$ and $Gr(k,\mathbb C)=\emptyset$ for $k\geq 2$.
 How on earth would you build $\mathbb P^1(\mathbb C)$ from pieces that are singleton sets or empty?