# The fundamental form is real of type $(1,1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-geometry

Given a real vector space $V$ with an almost complex structure $I$, and an inner product $\langle, \rangle$. Can define a fundamental form $(,):= \langle I(),() \rangle$. The claim is that is real of type $(1,1)$, i.e. $(,) \in \wedge^2 V^{\ast} \cap \wedge^{(1,1)}V^{\ast}$.

Why should it be real? It does not make sense at all, since if I take for instance $iv \in V_{\mathbb C}$, $v, w \in V$, then $(w, iv) = i(I(w), v)$ which is complex.
Also, why is it denoted by $\wedge^2 V^{\ast} \cap \wedge^{(1,1)}V^{\ast}$? Isn't $\wedge^{(1,1)}V^{\ast}$ a subspace of $\wedge^{2}V^{\ast}$?

This statement is taken from  [Introduction to Complex Geometry](https://www.math.uh.edu/~shanyuji/Complex/Complexgeometry.pdf) Lemma1.2.24, can someone clarify what it means by saying that the form is real?

Comment: Dear Vanstar, you may take a look at Chern's book "Complex Manifolds without Potential Theory". You are mixing some definitions.

Comment: @user90189 Can you point out which definitions I am missing out?

Comment: https://www.math.uh.edu/~shanyuji/Complex/Complexgeometry.pdf There is a good discussion here starting at page 25

Comment: @Alan Muniz That is actually where I am taking this from, so I am still confused.

Comment: I think the proof in Lemma 1.2.14  is clear. Check the definitions of each space involved.

Comment: @Alan Muniz Yes, but it does not explain why it is real. Maybe I am interpreting it wrong. May you at least clarify what it means for $w$ to be real? I am also confused why he has to denote the space by intersecting them since he pointed out in proposition 1.2.8 the latter is the subspace of the former.

Comment: Actually, $\Lambda^{1,1}V^* \subset \Lambda^2(V\otimes\Bbb C)^*$, no?

Comment: Formally no, but it can be identified with a subspace of the latter.@TedShifrin

Comment: @Vanstar  $\Lambda^{1,1}V^* \subset \Lambda^2(V\otimes\Bbb C)^*$ by definition!  Actually, $\Lambda^2V^*$ that is identified with the subspace of $\Lambda^2(V\otimes\Bbb C)^*$ given by the elements invariant by complex conjugation.

Comment: @AlanMuniz, I do not think that is true. Just take a look at the first statement of proposition 1.2.8. The issue is that the former object is defined as the tensor product of two subspaces of $(V_{\mathbb C})^{\ast}$ which is not a subspace of the wedge product to begin with. But it can certainly be identified as its subspace.

Answer (score 1):

This matter has also puzzled me for a long time.

$ V^*_{\mathbb{C}} $, the complexification of the dual space of $ V $, has a direct sum decomposition
$$V^*_\mathbb{C}=W^{1,0}\oplus W^{0,1}$$
since on $ V^* $ there is a natural complex structure induced by $ I $. Then we have
$$ \bigwedge^2 V^*_\mathbb{C}=\bigwedge^2 W^{1,0}\oplus W^{1,1}\oplus \bigwedge^2W^{0,1}, $$
where $ W^{1,1} $ is the image of
$$ \varphi\colon W^{1,0}\otimes W^{0,1}\longrightarrow \bigwedge^2 V^*_\mathbb{C},\quad f\otimes g\longmapsto f\wedge g. $$

Besides, for every $ \omega\in \bigwedge^2 V^* $, which can be regarded as an alternating function
$$ \omega\colon V\times V\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}, $$
can be extended by linear to (still denoted by $ \omega $)
$$ \omega\colon V_\mathbb{C}\times V_\mathbb{C}\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}. $$
In this way we embed $ \bigwedge^2 V^* $ into $ \bigwedge^2 V^*_{\mathbb{C}} $. Now we can talk about the intersection
$$ W^{1,1}_\mathbb{R}:=W^{1,1}\cap \bigwedge^2V^*\subset \bigwedge^2 V^*_{\mathbb{C}}. $$
We say elements of $ W^{1,1}_\mathbb{R} $ are alternating real form of type $ (1,1) $. Now it is clear how the name "real" and " type $ (1,1) $ " come from.

My references

- Huybrechts - Complex Geometry
- [https://people.brandeis.edu/~igusa/Math250b/Notes2020C.pdf](https://people.brandeis.edu/%7Eigusa/Math250b/Notes2020C.pdf)
- [Exterior power "commutes" with direct sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/822470/exterior-power-commutes-with-direct-sum)

Warnning: The notation in this answer such as $ W^{1,1}_\mathbb{R} $ may not be standard.