# How to construct the tensor product of two (non-commutative) algebras?

Tags: category-theory, tensor-products

It is known that the tensor product of two commutative algebras is their coproduct. It has to do with well-definedness of the multiplication for the homomorphism appearing from the universal property (it is very well explained in [Proof that the tensor product is the coproduct in the category of R-algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/984151/proof-that-the-tensor-product-is-the-coproduct-in-the-category-of-r-algebras?rq=1)).

On the other hand, there is a very good explanation about which the form of the elements into a general coproduct (not only for the commutative case) is in [How to construct the coproduct of two (non-commutative) rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/625874/how-to-construct-the-coproduct-of-two-non-commutative-rings) (extending to algebras). It takes a relation that makes the units to *disappear* all along the products.

My question is, since the tensor product of non-commutative algebras depends on a universal property and makes use of the *commutator* (according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_algebras): how that tensor can be constructed? Which are its elements and multiplication?

Comment: It's defined in the definition part of the wiki page. In particular, it's just the usual tensor product of modules, with the componentwise multiplication.

Comment: That's the point I wanted to reach: the multiplication for the quotient described nicely in: math.stackexchange.com/questions/625874/… does not satisfy the componentwise multiplication requirement. In fact, that description looks like the tensor algebra rather than the tensor product of algebras. I'm confused.